# Why OBD2 reader when cars have digital display?

Tags: obd-ii, diagnostics

I can see why separate OBD2 readers were needed before cars had a digital display. But now that they all do, why can't they just display the CEL code on the display instead of having to use a separate device to do so?

Comment: Don't know "why" exactly, but would bet it boils down to cost ... as if new vehicles don't cost enough already.

Comment: why would it cost any more? like they don't have a million applications running on that platform. the codes are already in the ECU, this would just display. a highschooler could write an application to read and display

Comment: Engineering costs, for one. Software development. It all costs money. And then they want an ROI on that development, so more money. Why add these additional costs when a mechanic already has those tools ... and then when it is available to the user, it makes it so the possibility you won't be coming into the dealership to get whatever it is fixed.

Comment: i would pay an extra $50 for a car that has it

Comment: And how much would it cost the dealerships in lost revenue?

Comment: Having customers self-diagnose is the worst and not only leads to hassles for the service advisor but also can lead to a bad customer experience.  Look into coolant temp gauges and why they had to put buffers on them.

Comment: It is a really good feature on my Jaguar XJS that fault codes are displayed on the trip computer.

Comment: @DamonEarl that is complete bullshit. that sort of rhetoric is designed to create job security for the technicians and treat customers like idiots

Comment: Good point. My sister-in-law had a "SRS" light come on and she had no idea why. Would have been nice if she could have found out what the problem was without taking the car in for service.

Answer (score 2):

Speaking for the U.S. market, cars and light trucks are required by law to have OBD2 ports that may be accessed via code readers and scan tools, and they must follow standardized codes and protocols.

[40 CFR § 86.1806-05](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/40/86.1806-05) is the U.S. federal law. Check it out, it's an interesting read if you're into legal technicalities. It goes into exquisite detail about exactly what the onboard diagnostics have to do. Did you know that a check engine light is not allowed to be red? I didn't!

There's no law that prohibits a vehicle manufacturer from displaying diagnostic information or codes on a digital display, but [an appendix](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/40/86.1806-05#h) to the above law gets into the weeds on the required interface which can not be omitted:

> (2) Light-duty vehicles and light-duty trucks must meet the following
> additional specifications:
>
> (i) Basic diagnostic data (as specified in §§ 86.094-17(e) and (f))
> shall be provided in the format and units in SAE J1979 “E/E Diagnostic
> Test Modes - Equivalent to ISO/DIS 15031-5: Revised, May 2007.
>
> (ii) Diagnostic trouble codes shall be consistent with SAE J2012
> “Diagnostic Trouble Code Definitions - Equivalent to ISO/DIS 15031-6:
> April 30, 2002”, (Revised, April 2002).
>
> (iii) The connection interface between the OBD system and test
> equipment and diagnostic tools shall meet the functional requirements
> of SAE J1962 “Diagnostic Connector - Equivalent to ISO/DIS 15031-3:
> December 14, 2001” (Revised, April 2002).
>
> (iv) SAE J1930, Revised April 2002. All acronyms, definitions and
> abbreviations shall be formatted according to this industry standard.
> Alternatively, manufacturers may use SAE J2403, Revised August 2007.
>
> (v) All equipment used to interface, extract, and display OBD-related
> information shall meet SAE J1978 “OBD II Scan Tool” Equivalent to ISO
> 15031-4: December 14, 2001”, (Revised, April 2002).

Later in the same appendix, the law provides for manufacturers to petition the government for an exemption from certain requirements, but "we have a better way to present diagnostic information" is not among the listed reasons for exemption.

So until federal law is changed, cars and light trucks sold in the USA will have standardized OBD2 ports accessible by standardized code readers and scan tools.

Comment: so basically, you're saying they only provide the diagnostics that are legally required and keep the customer in ignorance what's behind the scenes as much as possible in order to secure maintenance revenues for themselves as much as possible

Comment: @amphibient Nope, I didn't say that at all. They provide the diagnostic codes that are legally required because anything less will keep them out of the U.S. market. Full stop. Then some manufacturers go far beyond what is required and some don't. Is it possible that some car companies make corporate decisions about data disclosure that are legal but arguably unethical in order to maximize profits? Sure. That's what the "right to repair" movement is about. Anyone who cares about it should let their elected officials know how they feel about it.

Answer (score 1):

You ask why carmakers don't display "check engine light" codes. Instead, they just light up the "check engine" warning and force us to get the error code from the OBD2 port. That's a good question. Here's my answer.

Carmaking is a heavily regulated industry and an oligopoly (in other words, dominated by huge companies). Regulation and bigness tend to stifle innovation. Instead of trying new things and charging an innovation premium for them (like many companies in the computer industry do), carmakers tend to compete by optimizing and cost cutting.

That means carmakers do best by doing the bare minimum required by law. Take the On Board Diagnostics (OBD) standards. Those standards came out of California's Air Resources Board in the 1990s, and they require cars to alert drivers to the fact that their engines have a problem with emissions control.

The Environmental Protection Agency then imposed a similar, though not identical, regulation at the federal level. (The EPA calls its requirements just OBD. CARB is the one who calls its requirements OBD2.)

Note that these regulations did not come from the state or federal Department of Transportation, but the environmental agencies. They are not designed to help motorists maintain their cars (though indirectly they do), but to police motorists to reduce emissions.

In essence, the OBD regulations mean that a car continually monitors its emissions control system to make sure it is operating correctly. That is why smog tests no longer require a car to be tested on a dynamometer with a sensor stuck up its tailpipe. The technician just needs to plug into the OBD2 port, run the car briefly, and do a visual inspection to make sure you haven't cheated.

CARB is now considering what it calls OBD3, which would be remote monitoring. Your car would periodically report on the status of its emissions control system remotely by cell phone or some other method. You wouldn't have to go in for smog checks anymore, but your own car would snitch on you if a problem developed.

To get back to answering your question, carmakers usually do the minimum required for OBD because their focus is not on enforcing environmental regulations. Their focus is on selling cars. Most drivers, in my guess probably 99%, wouldn't benefit by knowing why their check engine light went on, so carmakers don't bother to tell them.

What would be nice is if the carmakers would allow you to buy and install a third-party app that could read sensor data off your car's CAN bus and put a notice about the problem on your touchscreen any time a fault came up. Then those who wanted the app could get the notice and those who didn't care wouldn't be bothered by a warning they didn't understand.

That kind of thing would be doable but carmakers have little incentive to do it. We are working on ways to give them an incentive. We'll see what happens.

Comment: who is the "we" in "We are working on ways to give them an incentive."?

Comment: My co-author and I ("we") are writing a book for SAE that has a chapter on this topic. There is a tension between standardization and customization that the carmakers have a tough time dealing with, yet don't want to allow third parties to step in with their own customizations. The issue is complex and there are no magical solutions, only tradeoffs. But we do have some ideas we will be pushing.